# Math Functions in Python Tkinter, and error message

Tags: python, math, tkinter, calculator

I have to create a 5 function calculator in Python with Tkinter that deals with 2 variables and provides an exit.  There also needs to be an error message.  I have laid out the calculator and defined the functions but nothing happens.  Also, any idea how to add in the error message.  Right now when you press a button the error message (insert the name of the function) missing 1 required positional argument: 'app'.  I am completely stuck and can't figure it out.  I am obviously very new to this.  I am sure it is something simple.  Thank you!

```
from tkinter import *    
from math import *
app = Tk()
app.title('Calculator')
app.geometry('400x500')

Label(app, text = "Welcome to Calculator 2013. Enjoy!").pack(padx = 10, pady = 10) 
Label(app, text = "Enter both of your variables and then pick your computations below.").pack(pady = 10)   

global var1, var2, total
Label(text='First Variable').pack()
var1 = Entry()
var1.insert(0,0)
var1.pack()
Label(text='Final Variable').pack()
var2 = Entry()
var2.insert(0,0)
var2.pack()
Label(text='Total').pack()
Total = Entry()
Total.pack()


def add():
    global var1, var2, total
    first = float(var1.get())
    second = float(entry.get())
    total = first + second
    total.delete(0,END)
    total.insert(0, str(total))      
def subtract(app):
    global var1, var2, total
    first = float(var1.get())
    second = float(var2.get())
    total = first - second
    total.delete(0,END)
    total.insert(0, str(total))
def divide(app):
    global var1, var2, total
    first = float(var1.get())
    second = float(var2.get())
    total = first / second
    total.delete(0,END)
    total.insert(0, str(total))
def multiply(app):
    global var1, var2, total
    first = float(var1.get())
    second = float(var2.get())
    total = first * second
    total.delete(0,END)
    total.insert(0, str(total))
def clear(app):
    global var1, var2, total
    var1.delete(0,END)
    var2.delete(0,END)
    total.delete(0,END)
def quit(app):
    app.destroy()


b_add = Button(app, text="+", bg="green", fg="black", width = 5, font=12, command = add).pack(side=LEFT)
b_sub = Button(app, text="-", bg="red", fg="white", width = 5, font=12, command = subtract).pack(side=LEFT)
b_sub = Button(app, text="*", bg="blue", fg="white", width = 5, font=12, command = multiply).pack(side=LEFT)
b_div = Button(app, text="/", bg="yellow", fg="black", width = 5, font=12, command = divide).pack(side=LEFT)
b_clear = Button(app, text="Clear", bg="black", fg="white", width = 5, font=12, command = clear).pack(side=LEFT)
b_exit = Button(app, text="Exit?", bg="white", fg="red", width = 40, font=12, command = quit).pack(side=LEFT)


app.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", quit)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for posting your code, but please put a little more description in your question: what problem are you having, what is the result you expect, and [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far? Going through the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) will help us better answer your question. Thanks!

Comment: @ChristianTernus Took martin's advice? ;)

Answer (score 0):

The error message "missing 1 required positional argument: 'app'." stems from the fact you've defined most of your functions to accept an argument named "app", but when you push a button you aren't passing that argument in. The simple solution is to remove `app` from the definition of the functions.

For example, do this:

```
def multiply():
    ...
```

rather than this:

```
def multiply(app):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  Now I have fixed that  but am getting this error message 'float' object has no attribute 'delete' line 33

Comment: @user2921919: maybe you meant to use `Total.delete()`? You have variables named `total` and `Total` and they mean different things.

Comment: I had no idea that mattered.  Thanks.  With that correction it is still giving the error message though.

Comment: @user2921919: first rule of debugging is to trust that the error message is telling the truth. If it says "x has no attribute y", that can only mean one thing: you have an object x, you are trying to access attribute y,and x does not have such an attribute. You then simply need to ask yourself "why?". Either x should have attribute y and you failed to create it, or x isn't what you think it is. Usually it's the latter. If you're getting "x has no attribute y", you're making an assumption about x that is false. Again, ask yourself "why?".